# Dystopian England-like Land, Monsters come out at night

Tags: story-identification

So, I'm trying to remember the name of a series of books that I read years ago, probably during the early-to-mid 00's.

It was set in a dystopian Victorian-era England-like land, where there was a main highway that had lanterns. The lanterns had be lit each night to keep monsters at bay, and the story revolved around a young boy who was training to light these lanterns.  I think there was some magic involved somewhere and by the end of the second novel I think the young boy had become part-monster or something.

Anyone know the books I'm talking about? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the "Monster Blood Tattoo" series, by D. M. Cornish.  This first is called Foundling, the second Lamplighter, the third Factotum.  (Just looking at [the website](http://monsterbloodtattoo.blogspot.co.nz/), the series title is "The Foundling's Tale" in the US and Canada.)

The young boy is Rossamund, who is an orphan.  He trains to be a lamplighter, who are, as you say, the people who light the lamps that keep the monsters away from the road.

There is a mystery around the boy, as he is a foundling, but the caretakers at the orphanage seem to know something about him, and tell him he must keep using a special perfume or potion. He feels a sympathy towards the monsters he meets and sees killed.

This is an excellent series, and you have reminded me to go and read it again!

Comment: Ah! Beautiful! I thought there was something about lights in the title. Thanks, that was driving me nuts! :D

Comment: It's a great series, a really well-made world. I was going to write more of a synopsis but thought you would probably find and read all the books now, so I didn't want to spoil it for you!